# Align 1,500 Time-Lapse Pictures

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, alignment

I took 1,500 pictures of a scene but unfortunately the tripod was not stable.
When I rendered the video, it did not look good.
I tried to aligning with the help of Photoshop, but wasn't successful.
I tried stack function, it took too long and in the end it crashed.
Then I opened all images in layers and tried auto align function, but no luck there either.
Is there some easy way to align all images?
Maybe someway to align all images to one image and then crop, or some other way.

Comment: If each shot has movement, auto aligning in PS will not work, since the software cannot "know" which parts of the image should be still and which should be moving. I think you would either have to align them manually, or fix the tripod and shoot again, or perhaps use a video editor and attempt some kind of video stabilization.

Comment: Adobe After Effects will do the job as mentioned in the Answers below as well as other software with a tracking capability. When you finish, the stabilized and software-aligned portion of the sequence will be cropped (clipped) from the viewable area as it is not common to all processed frames. The amount of clipping will be comparable to the amount of tripod-instability

Comment: @Stan I used this technique but with adobe premiere pro. thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you all for the helpful responses. I solved the problem with the help of your answers. 
Since I took help form you answers but there was not a complete solution, so I decided to post the complete solution by myself. 
1) Import image sequence to adobe premiere pro (CC 2017 in my case). Premiere will make one video file out of all images instead of importing all images.
2) you can right click on the imported file and change the sequence properties as desired. (I changed the frame rate to 60fps).
3) move sequence to the editing panel.
4) search for the "warp stabilizer" in the effects, and drag it over your video. it will take some time to analyze but not very long. then it will stabilize the movements from the time-laps video.
5) In the effect setting apply no-motion in the result. so that the stabilized video will be still and focused on one scene. 
(Remember it is the movement caused by shaky tripod. that is why you do not want any motion in the stabilization.)
6) Go to file > export > media. There you can select the quality and format. 
Hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you are trying to stabilize the sequence of images. Use editing or compositing software like Fusion, Nuke, After Effects... There you can track some points and stabilize the sequence.

Comment: Or specialized tracking application like syntheyes.

Comment: I think the software feature required is typically called either "image stabilization" or "motion interpolation"

Comment: @Yorik Thanks for the tip. adobe premiere pro did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using Photoshop, if you set a layer to difference, you will see where it differs from the layer under. So you could import your images in Photoshop, find a place that doesn't move in your time lap and use this as a reference point. Then export as an animated GIF, or crop and re-exported as stable images. However this might be quite too time consuming if you need to rotate images and not just move them horizontally/vertically.